# Openshift app is getting SIGTERM each 6 hours

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am playing with node.js in OpenShift. I have realized that my app is getting SIGTERM periodically each 6 hours.

Log looks like this:

```
DEBUG: Sending SIGTERM to child...
DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with
DEBUG:   program 'app/run.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/<appId>/app-root/data/.nodewatch'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node app/run.js'
DEBUG: Watching directory '/var/lib/openshift/<appId>/app-root/data/.nodewatch' for changes.
```

Is this an OpenShift feature? How can I disable it?

Comment: Have you checked your memory usage? https://developers.openshift.com/en/troubleshooting-faq.html#_why_is_my_application_restarting_automatically_or_having_memory_issues

Comment: @coreydaley Both counters are `0`.